# Extending a partial order to a total order

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I came across the question below in Velleman's How to prove it:

Suppose $R$ is a partial order on a set $A$, $B\subseteq A$, and $B$ is ﬁnite. Prove
that there is a partial order $T$ on $A$ such that $R\subseteq T$ and $\forall x \in B\forall y\in A(xTy\vee yTx )$. (Hint: Use induction on the number of elements in $B$. For the induction step, assume the 
conclusion holds for any set $B \subseteq A$ with $n$ elements, and suppose $B$ is a subset of $A$ with $n + 1$ 
elements. Let $b$ be any element of $B$ and let $B' = B \backslash \{ b\}$, a subset of $A$ with $n$ elements. By 
inductive hypothesis, let $T'$ be a partial order on $A$ such that $R \subseteq T'$ and $\forall x\in B'\forall y\in A(xT'y\vee 
yT'x )$. Now let  $A_1 = \{ x\in A \mid xT'b\}$ and $A_2 = A \backslash A_1$ , and let $T = T' \cup ( A_1 \times A_2 )$. Prove that 
$T$  has all the
required properties.)

Proving $T$ has all the properties isn't hard, my problem is: why the sets $A_1$ and $A_2$ are defined like that? How do we know how to define $A_1$ and $A_2$ like this so the partial order $R$ can be extended to a total order. Can anyone please provide a full explanation to this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you did the proof, then you would know why you need the set $A1$ -- it's all the values "less than" your added additional element $b$. Therefore all the other elements $A2$ have to be "greater than" $b$ for all the elements to be comparable to $b$. (And therefore everything in A1 has to be "less than" everything in A2.)

Comment: @tabstop Do you mean the set A1 and A2 make sure that the element b is comparable to every element in A?

Comment: I agree with your perplexity; with $T = T' \cup (A_1 \times A_2)$ we will have that for all $x \in A_1$, $b$ is "greater then.". We have also that all $x \in A_1$ are "less then" all other elements of $A$. But what about $b$ itself ? How the proposed extension of $T'$ order it compared to elements on $A_2$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof by induction.

*Base step*

We must start with $B = \{ b_0 \}$.

We define $A_1 = \{ x \in A : xRb_0 \}$ and $A_2 = A \backslash A_1$, and we "extend" the partial order $R$ as follows :

> $T = R \cup (A_1 \times A_2)$.

We will check if it works, i.e. if $\forall x \in B$ , $\forall y \in A$ , $x$ and $y$ are "comparable" according to $T$.

But $B = \{ b_0 \}$ and $b_0 \in A_1$, because $b_0Rb_0$, by def of partial order.

So, for all $x \in A_1$, we have that $x$ is "less or equal than" $b_0$, while for all other $x$, because they are in $A_2$, we have that $b_0$ is "less or equal than" $x$.

It is then verified that, with the extension $T$ of $R$, all elements of $B$ (i.e.$b_0$) are "comparable" to all elements of $A$.

We have to prove that $T$ is a partial order on $A$, i.e. *reflexivity*, *anti-simmetry* and *transitivity*.

For *reflexivity* : $xRx$, so that $xTx$.

For *anti-simmetry* : assume that $xTy$ and $yTx$; we have four cases:

*(i)* $xRy$ and $yRx$, then $x=y$, by *anti-symm* of $R$;

*(ii)* $xRy$ and $<y,x> \in A_1 \times A_2$; but $y \in A_1 \rightarrow yRb_0$, and $x \in A_2 \rightarrow b_0Rx$, so that $yRx$ by *transitivity* of $R$. But then we have $xRy$ and $yRx$, so that again $x=y$.

*(iii)* $<x,y> \in A_1 \times A_2$ and $yRx$; $x \in A_1 \rightarrow xRb_0$ and $y \in A_2 \rightarrow b_0Ry$, so that $xRy$ and again $x=y$.

*(iv)* $<x,y> \in A_1 \times A_2$ and $<y,x> \in A_1 \times A_2$; but this implies that $x,y \in A_1 \cap A_2 = \emptyset$ : contradiction.

For *transitivity*, we proceed in the same way.

*Induction step*

When we prove the induction step, we have the set $B$ with $n+1$ elements, we pick an element $b \in B$ and we consider $B' = B \backslash \{ b \}$, that is a set with $n$ elements.

By induction hypo, B' is ordered by $T'$ extending $R$ such that :

> $\forall x \in B' \forall y \in A (xT'y \lor yT'x )$.

But now, where is $b$ ?  Because we have "excluded" $b$ from $B'$, when in the previous step we have obtained the "full comparability" of elements of $B'$ respect to elements of $A$, that by induction hypo we are assuming to exists, $b$ was not in $B'$ but was, of course, an element of $A$; so in the induction hypo we are "assuming" that it is comparable to all elements of $B'$.

When we build the sets :

> $A_1 = \{ x \in A : xT'b \}$ and $A_2 = A \backslash A_1$ ,

all elements of $B'$ will be partitioned between $A_1$ and $A_2$ and $b$ is in $A_1$, because by def of partial order : $bT'b$.

We will define :

> $T = T' \cup (A_1 \times A_2)$.

Again, we will check the definition; we already know that all $x \in B'$ are comparable to all $y \in A$; we have only to verify it for $b$. Take any $y \in A$ :

> if $y \in A_1$, then $yT'b$, so that $yTb$;
>
> if $y \in A_2$, then we have $bTy$, by construction, and it's done.

Comment: Why <b,b>∉T′ ? I thought that partial order is reflexive. And when you said "T does not 'say nothing", did you mean 'anything' instead of 'nothing'?

Comment: @DaveClifford - you are right; I'm not licensed to assume that it is a *strict* partial order.

Comment: For an element x, if it is not the case that xRb, you set it so it becomes bRx, are you doing that because you need every element to be able to compare with each other? You can't set it xRb because this will contradicts the definition of the partial order R right?

Comment: @DaveClifford - we need that all elements of $B$ **must be** comparable to all elements of $A$; the "trick" is needed in order to exploit the properties of the partial order $R$ for proving that also $T$ is a partial order, in addition to assuring the "total comparability" of elements of $B$ respect to elements of $A$.