# Suppose $A$ is a finite set and $R$ is a partial order on $A$. Prove that $R$ can be extended to a total order on $A$.

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, induction

> Suppose $A$ is a finite set and $R$ is a partial order
>   on $A$. Prove that $R$ can be extended to a total order on $A$. In
>   other words, prove that there is a total order $T$ on $A$ such that $R
>  ⊆ T$.

My attempt:

Notation and abbreviations:

1. Cardinality of the set, say $A$, is denoted as $|A|$.
2. Partial order will be abbreviated as PO, and total order will be abbreviated as TO.

---

By induction.

**Base case**

Take $A = \{x\}$. The only possible PO on $A$ is $\{(x,x)\}$. Clearly, it is also a TO on $A$.

**Induction step**

Suppose for any set with $n$ elements, any PO on the set can be extended to TO.

Now take $A = |n+1|$.

Take arbitrary PO on $A$, say $R$. Need to prove that $R$ can be extended to TO.

---

Take $a \in A$, such that $a$ *is the R-minimal element of $A$*.

Let $A' = A \setminus \{a\}$.

Let $R' = \{(x,y) \mid xRy \land x ≠ a\}$

It can be shown that $R'$ is a PO on $A'$, and by inductive hypothesis we conclude that there exists some $T'$, such that $R' \subseteq T'$ and $T'$ is a TO on $A'$.

Now let $T = T' \cup \{(a,x) \mid x \in A \}$.

It can be shown that $R \subseteq T$. Now we need to show that $T$ is TO on $A$.

In other words, we need to prove that

1. $T$ is reflexive
2. $T$ is transitive
3. $T$ is antisymmetric
4. For all $x \in A$ and for all $y \in A$, either $xTy$ or $yTx$.

---

1. Reflexive: take $x \in A$. Clearly if $x = a$ then $(x,x) \in T$. Now suppose $x ≠ a$. Then $x \in A'$ and $(x,x) \in T'$. Since $T' \subseteq T$, $(x,x) \in T$.
2. Transitive: take $(x,y),(y,z) \in T$ and suppose $x ≠ a$. We know that $y ≠ a$. And since $y ≠ a$, both elemetns are in $T'$. $T'$ is TO on $A'$, hence $xT'z$, and therefore $xTz$
3. Antisymmetric: Take $(x,y) \in T$ and suppose $x ≠ a$. We know that $xT'y$ and $T'$ is antisymmetric, hence $\lnot yT'x$ and $\lnot yTx$. Now suppose $aTy$. By definition of $T$, we conclude that $\lnot yTa$
4. - Take $x,y \in A$, such that $x ≠ a$ and $y ≠ a$. $x \in A'$ and $y \in A'$, hence either $xT'y$ and $yT'x$. And since $T' \subseteq T$, we conclude that either $xTy$ or $yTx$.
   - Take $a, y \in A$. Since $(a,y) \in \{(a,x) \mid x \in A \}$, we have $aTy$.

Hence $T$ is a TO. $\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: Note that there need not be an $R$-minimal element. For example, when $R$ is the relation $\{(a, a) \mid a \in A\}$.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677126/extending-a-partial-order-to-a-total-order?rq=1).

Comment: @MeesdeVries The definition of the minimal element from the book I'm reading: If $R \subseteq B \times B$ and $b$ is an $R$-minimal element of $B$, then $\lnot \exists x \in B (xRb \land x ≠ b)$. And the definition of the smallest element: if $b$ is the R-smallest element of $B$, then $\forall x \in B(bRx)$. So in the example provided by you, according the definitions I listed, there *will* be a minimal element. Perhaps what you meant is, there won't be the **smallest** element.